# How to export a set of url in python

Tags: python, shell, unix, export

I have two files namings trigger.sh and emp.py in LocalDB folder.

In trigger.sh I have

```
export emp_code='IT'
py /C/Users/LocalDB/emp.py
```

In emp.py

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import is filed,join

_emp_code=os.environ['emp_code']

Emp_url = {
'IT':{'Emp_url':'www.it.com'},
'Prod':{'Emp_url':'www.prod.com'},
'Qa':{'Emp_url':'www.qa.com'}
}[_emp_code]
Print(Emp_url)
```

When I trigger trigger.sh my output
""**'Emp_url':'www.it.com'**"....Similarly if I change my emp_code in shell script it will change ..

Now,I am trying to have these url in Shell script.But am getting an "Not valid identifier".

Below code I have tried :
Trigger.sh

```
export emp_code='IT'
export _emp_url= '
'IT':{'Emp_url':'www.it.com'},
'Prod':{'Emp_url':'www.prod.com'},
'Qa':{'Emp_url':'www.qa.com'}'
py /C/Users/LocalDB/emp.py
```

emp.py:

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import is filed,join

_emp_code=os.environ['emp_code']
Emp_url = os.environ ['_emp_url']

Emp_url = {Emp_url}[_emp_code]
Print(Emp_url)
```

Any idea on how to resolve and clear this one

Comment: Your emp.py files contain syntax errors as does your second version of Trigger.sh. Furthermore, even if you set an environment variable to a value that is a string representation of a Python dictionary, you're going to need to do some more work in order to be able to process it - e.g., ast.literal_eval()

Comment: In your first code, `Emp_url` is a Hash. In your second code piece, `Emp_url` is a String (because this is what you get from `os.environ`), but you never parse this string to produce a Hash.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I am trying to have these url in Shell script. But am getting an
> "Not valid identifier".

This error message is typically displayed when you try to do an `export` with a string that is not a valid shell variable name. The shell expects no spaces between the shell variable name, the `=` sign and the value being assigned. Anything following a space on the `export` line is expected to be another valid shell variable name possibly followed by `=` for value assignment.

In the script Trigger.sh, the first line looks correct; the second line is wrong. In the 2nd line there is a space after `=` which makes the shell expect a shell variable name (an "identifier") but what follows is a string with many characters not allowed in an identifier (multiple `:`, `{`, `}` and newline characters).

In emp.py, this line

```
from os.path import is filed,join
```

is wrong, the word `is` should not be there.

```
[ ranga ] $ python3
Python 3.9.13
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> from os import listdir
>>> from os.path import is filed,join
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from os.path import is filed,join
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

After this line:

```
Emp_url = os.environ ['_emp_url']
```

`Emp_url` contains only a string, not a `dict`.

So, in this line:

```
Emp_url = {Emp_url}[_emp_code]
```

the `{Emp_url}` creates a `set` with a single entry with the whole string in it, then trying to index it with `_emp_code` (another string) will fail.

The string in Emp_url needs to be converted into a `dict` before indexing it with a string. One way to do this is to use the `json` package:

```
import json
Emp_url = json.loads(os.environ['_emp_url'])
```

For this, the environment variable `_emp_url` should contain double quotes and not single quotes. Also to print only the URL:

```
print Emp_url['Emp_url']
```

In Trigger.sh:

- on line 2, remove the space after the '='
- on line 3 and 4, replace all instances of single quote with double quote
- on line 5, replace all instances of single quote, except the last, with double quote

So now
Trigger.sh can have something like:

```
export \
  emp_code='IT' \
  _emp_url='{
    "IT":{"Emp_url":"www.it.com"},
    "Prod":{"Emp_url":"www.prod.com"},
    "Qa":{"Emp_url":"www.qa.com"}
  }'
py /C/Users/LocalDB/emp.py
```

and emp.py can have something like

```
import os
import json

_emp_code=os.environ['emp_code']
Emp_urls = json.loads(os.environ ['_emp_url'])

Emp_url = Emp_urls[_emp_code]['Emp_url']
print(Emp_url)
```

Trying it:

```
[ ranga ] $ export \
>   emp_code='IT' \
>   _emp_url='{
>     "IT":{"Emp_url":"www.it.com"},
>     "Prod":{"Emp_url":"www.prod.com"},
>     "Qa":{"Emp_url":"www.qa.com"}
>   }'


[ ranga ] $ python3
Python 3.9.13 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import json
>>>
>>> _emp_code=os.environ['emp_code']
>>> Emp_urls = json.loads(os.environ ['_emp_url'])
>>>
>>> Emp_url = Emp_urls[_emp_code]['Emp_url']
>>> print(Emp_url)
www.it.com
>>>
```